# Как использовать модуль asyncio в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot, asyncio

```
import telebot
import asyncio
list = []

bot = telebot.AsyncTeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler()
async def get_message(message):
    if str(message.chat.id) not in list:
        list.append(str(message.chat.id))
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        list.remove(str(message.chat.id))
    if str(message.chat.id) in list:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Попробуй позже")

asyncio.run(bot.polling())
```

Когда приходит сообщение высвечивается ошибка

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_message' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Как использовать модуль asyncio в telebot?" - Скорее всего, никак. Разумных путей не видно.

Судя по [документации](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#message-handlers) `telebot` не поддерживает асинхронность. Декоратор заточен на обычные функции, а не корутины.

А судя по [реализации AsyncTeleBot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L2129) (в документации тоже об этом говорится) - это всего лишь модификация `TeleBot`, которая любой вызов API выносит в отдельный поток, после чего результаты вызова просто можно дождаться потом, а параллельно делать что-то другое. Никакого отношения к ключевым словам `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. AsyncTeleBot уже создал за тебя корутину при получении сообщения, так что уже выполняет это действие в отдельном потоке по этому тебе нужно добавить await перед sending_message

```
await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Попробуй позже")
```